# How to create Date picker field in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I need Date picker field in visualforce page.

When select that field the date format should like YYYY-MM-DD

How to achieve this?

Thanks for all your response..

Comment: If your new to VF development http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf is a good starting point/reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can bind directly to a date field on an sObject(in my example contact) using Visualforce like this:

`<apex:inputField value="{!Contact.BirthDate}" />`

Visualforce will render as appropriate based on the data type of your field. So if your using standard Salesforce styles in your page, this will cause the salesforce default calendar to be displayed. Otherwise you can take a look [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Datepicker-in-Visualforce-page/td-p/396825) for some more ideas. Also it may be worthwhile to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516549/how-to-format-a-date-in-visualforce) for info on how you can format dates in VF.

Comment: but in native salesforce picker format is MMDDYYYY but he wants it to be in the format YYYYMMDD.

Comment: Ok well maybe the following link will help :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834873/salesforce-apex-validating-date-for-format-and-value

Comment: Note that if the user doesn't have write access to the proxy object's field, it will render on the screen as a read-only value.

Answer (score 0):

Native salesforce picker format is `MMDDYYYY`. To change it into `YYYYMMDD`, use below JavaScript code example:

```
var EffDate=document.getElementById("effdate").value;
if (EffDate) { 
    EffDate = EffDate.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/, function(match,y,m,d) { 
        return m + '/' + d + '/' + y;  
    });
}
```